# Custom test names for test methods in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'd like to know if anyone has found a solution for writing human-readable method tests names, so non-tech guys may read test list and they'll be able to understand what's going on, and, in instance, programmers won't need to use "non-tech-guy-friendly naming conventions" like "Whatever_Whatever2_Whatever3_DoesHelloWorldTest" anymore...?

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot to be said for the clear and understandable convention:

```
MethodName_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior
```

(not restricted to VS2010 or even .NET)

Comment: I follow this same convention.